# Forwarding reference types for lamdas capture list

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates

I have the following code:

```
template<class Callable, class ...Args>
void f(Callable t, Args &&... args)
{
    auto lambda = [t, args...](){ t(args...); };
}

int main()
{
    int x = 8;
    using callable_t = decltype(std::greater{});
    f(std::greater{}, x, 10);
}
```

If I understand correctly (correct me if I'm wrong), the compiler generates the following function:

```
void f(callable_t t, int& x, int&& y);
```

All I want to achieve is to make sure that in the lambda capture list, x is captured by reference and y is captured by value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your example did not work. Simply print out the result in case you modify x inside main. If it is used by ref the result should change but it did not... try again :-)

Comment: I know C++20 lets you `...args = std::forward<Args>(args)`, but I'm not sure whether that captures an rvalue by value or if it would have be an rvalue reference. You can pass the pack to a function taking `(int&, int&&)` using `std::forward<Args>(args)...`, but not with the usual `decltype(args)(args)...` alternative. Rather, that matches `(int&&, int&&)`, which someone will know more about than me.

Comment: Actually, looking on cppinsights, it has both captures as plain `int` in that case.

Comment: It seems impossible to select the capture type by template metaprogramming, but you can always capture a custom wrapper by value and make it either a reference wrapper or a value wrapper, depending on what is being wrapped.

Comment: You can do `[t, tup = std::tuple<Args...>{args...}]{ apply(t, tup); }`